# Process template change for a VSTS project - Impacts/points to be noted

Tags: azure-devops

What are the impacts and suggestions when we decided to switch the project process template from one to other (for example, would like to move from scrum to agile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no impact, nor can anyone provide any suggestions, because **you cannot change between system process templates**. Scrum, Agile, and CMMI are all system templates. Thus, you cannot change between them.

You can create [*inherited*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=vsts) process templates and change between those freely.

Comment: Thank you Daniel!